# Are there matrices with with non-real elements?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I know that the definition of a matrix is a rectangular arrangement of elements, which are real numbers. But does there exist such a thing as a rectangular arrangement of complex numbers? How are these matrices called, if they exist?

Comment: Complex matrices.

Comment: {quaternion, complex, octonion, infinitesimal, polygremlic} matrices.

Comment: Yes, complex matrices, check out this link :)
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complex+matrix

Comment: Matrices whose entries are complex numbers are frequently used.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was quite uneducated back when I asked this question, so now the answer is trivial to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entries in a matrix can be anything at all as long as multiplication and addition are things that make sense for it. Formalizing this notion is the concept of a ring, an algebraic structure with two operations, addition and multiplication, under some familiar axioms. Then, one can consider matrices with entries in a ring. This includes real matrices (i.e., matrices in the ring $\mathbb R$), complex matrices (i.e., matrices in the ring $\mathbb C$), but also many other possibilities like matrices whose entries are polynomials, or matrices whose entries are themselves matrices (all of the same size).